# Highcharts: move renderer (custom drawn)

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am using highcharts to plot ~100,000 points.

I'd like to plot "draw" various rectangles underneath based upon some custom data.  Essentially just start location and length of rectangle.  Upon zoom the rectangles stay and aren't "adjusted".

I have a simple fiddle, but the rectangles drawn here are a small subset.

http://jsfiddle.net/n2549ewg/1/

```
 chart.renderer.rect(x1, y2, x2 - x1, y1 - y2)
                .attr({ 
                     fill: 'blue'
                 }).add();
```

Is there a way that all custom renderers can get scaled automatically?
A working example would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rectangles' positions have to be recalculated. You can do this on redraw event, but you need the generated random numbers which you used during  the rectangles creation.

Add the code below inside the loop and each rectangle coordinates will be preserved.

```
rectangle = {
  start: start,
  len: len,
  ystart: ystart,
  yend: yend,
  element: chart.renderer.rect(x1, y2, x2 - x1, y1 - y2)
    .attr({
      fill: 'blue'
    }).add()
};

chart.rectangles.push(rectangle);
```

On redraw recalculate their position according to the new scales - after zooming x and y axes changed their scales.

```
events: {
    redraw: function() {
      var xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
          yAxis = this.yAxis[0];

      this.rectangles.forEach(function (rect) {
         var x1 = xAxis.toPixels(rect.start),
             x2 = xAxis.toPixels(rect.len),
             y1 = yAxis.toPixels(rect.ystart),
             y2 = yAxis.toPixels(rect.yend);

        rect.element.attr({
          x: x1,
          y: y2,
          width: x2 - x1,
          height: y1 - y2
        });
      });
    }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/n2549ewg/4/

As you can see in the example, the rects get also bigger when zooming. If you want to avoid that behaviour, then leave the width and height untouched. The rects will have adjusted positions but their size will remain the same.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/n2549ewg/5/

Comment: Ok... your answer makes sense, but on both fiddles, the "Reset Zoom" will not reset the rectangles to the correct y position. Also... when zooming, the rectangles doesn't stay on the bottom axis.  The height should never be altered... just the width.

Comment: Yes, I didn't recalculate moving down y points of 50 pixels to the bottom - which also need to be included in rect's values. But my exaplanation is still correct - transform rect's coords to axis values, and on redraw transform them to pixels, so they can be respositioned. If you want height in values, then leave it as it is - don't transform between values and pixels.